# Fill Down values from a 1x6 array into an _x6 array Google App Script for Google Sheet

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, range, rows

I've got this:

```
array_to_fill_down = [a, b, c, cat, 15, blue]
rows = 3
```

What I want is this:
array_output

```
[
{a, b, c, cat, 15, blue},
{a, b, c, cat, 15, blue},
{a, b, c, cat, 15, blue}
]
```

Sorry, I know I'm probably not using the correct symbols. That's part of my problem, I'm sure.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably something like this:

```
array_to_fill_down = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'cat', 15, 'blue'];
rows = 3;

var new_array = [];
while (rows--) new_array.push(array_to_fill_down)
```

Or

```
var new_array = new Array(rows).fill(array_to_fill_down);
```

Not sure if I understand your goal, though.

---

**Update**

The code above creates the *references* on the original array. Say, if you change one element of the original array it will change every row of the new array. It causes the nasty errors pretty often. If you want to have genuine independent copies instead of references it can be done this way:

```
array_to_fill_down = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'cat', 15, 'blue'];
rows = 3;

var new_array = [];
while (rows--) new_array.push(array_to_fill_down.slice()); // <-- HERE
```

The second one-liner with Array.fill() method can't do it.

Comment: It won't let me mark this as "useful", because I don't have enough "reputation". But this is exactly what I needed. I think Array(rows).fill(array_to_fill_down) will be much faster than a while loop, so that's what I'll use.

Comment: @Yuri is this the recommended way to replicate items and populate an array in JS? I'm new to the language, but in python there's a way to do `new_array = [array_to_fill_down] * 3`... It's supposed to be more memory efficient. Have you come across any posts regarding this?

Comment: @RichieV it's an interesting question. But I have no answer. Efficiency y in JS is a tricky matter. And it's even more tricky in Google Script because the script is running on the server side within the god knows how optimized environment. You have to test it by yourself. And yes, Python is well designed for such tasks, I would surprised if it's more efficent.

Comment: And in this particular case is the one danger thing: these rows-arrays are **references** on the same original array. Say If you change first element in the original array, it will change every first element in every row of the new 2d array.

Answer (score 2):

You've asked for a script specifically. But in the event that you or a future site visitor wanted to do this with a formula:

`=ArrayFormula(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT({"a";"b";"c";"cat";15;"blue"}&"~",3),"~",1,0)))`

If the array to repeat were to be entered into a horizontal range (say, A1:F1):

`=ArrayFormula(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(TRANSPOSE(A1:F1)&"~",3),"~",1,0)))`

And if that to-be-filled array were entered into a vertical range (say, A1:A6):

`=ArrayFormula(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(A1:A6&"~",3),"~",1,0)))`

Answer (score 1):

```js
console.log([...Array.from({length:3}, x => ['a', 'b', 'c', 'cat', 15, 'blue'])])
console.log([...Array.from(Array(3), x => ['a', 'b', 'c', 'cat', 15, 'blue'])])
```